# Can I have two RETURN clauses in Cypher query?

Tags: cypher, graph-databases, memgraphdb

I'm going through my first tutorial on [Memgraph Playgound](https://playground.memgraph.com/). In [one od the lessons](https://playground.memgraph.com/lesson/game-of-thrones-deaths-introductions-1-playground?step=0) there is the following code:

```
MATCH (jon:Character { name: "Jon Snow" })-[killed:KILLED]->(character:Character)
RETURN jon, killed, character;
```

From the graph and the table, I can see that result returns 17 nodes.

I've modified the query to get the number of nodes instead of list of nodes:

```
MATCH (jon:Character { name: "Jon Snow" })-[killed:KILLED]->(character:Character)
RETURN count(jon);
```

Is it possible to have a query that would return both results at the same time, the count of nodes, as well as individual nodes? I've tried something like the following code but it doesn't work:

```
MATCH (jon:Character { name: "Jon Snow" })-[killed:KILLED]->(character:Character)
RETURN jon, killed, character;
RETURN count(jon);
```

Can you have more than one RETURN in a single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `WITH` clause to pass the results from one part of the query to another.
The `WITH` clause allows you to use the results of the first part of the query in the second part.

```
MATCH (jon:Character { name: "Jon Snow" })-[killed:KILLED]->(character:Character)
WITH jon, killed, character, count(jon) as node_count
RETURN jon, killed, character, node_count;
```